# Image gallery control for c# windows applications

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Are there any image gallery control for c# windows application??

something like, javaScript image galleries.Such as ([slideViewr](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html))

Regards

Kushan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are plenty on codeplex - take a look:

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=image%20viewer&ac=2

here's one that looks good: http://keyboardimageviewer.codeplex.com/

you might also like to adapt code from: http://ecomic.codeplex.com/